# Question about Poisson processes

Tags: probability

I'm given that during some 30-day month (say, November), a chime randomly rings according to a Poisson process with a rate of one chime every six days.

Letting $A$ represent the number of days in this month that will have ***at least*** one chime, I'm trying to find $E(A)$.

Would $E(A)$ just equal $\lambda = {30\over6} = 5$?

Or would I have to solve for:

$$P(N(1)\ge 1) = 1 - P(N(1)=0)$$
$$= 1 - {({1\over6})^0*e^{-{1\over6}}\over{0!}}$$
$$E(A) = n*p=30*p\approx4.606$$
... where I have $\lambda = {1\over6}$ and $t=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is the second, due to the following reasoning.

The number of days with at least one chime (success) $A$ in a time period of 30 days is a binomial random variable with paremeters $n=30$ and $p$ given by $$p=P(N(1)\ge1)$$ where $N(1)\sim \mathrm{Poisson} (λ=1/6)$, exactly as you have it. So, the expected value of $A$ is $$E[A]=np$$ as your second approach yields.

Your first approach gives "the expected number of *chimes* in this month" (which is 5, as you correctly calculated) and not "the expected number of *days with more than one chime* in this month".

Comment: This may be more what the OP was looking for than my answer (+1)

Comment: @robjohn Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your cogent explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of chimes would be $1/6$ in a day, thus the formula for the probability of $k$ chimes in a given day would be
$$
\frac1{6^kk!}e^{-1/6}
$$
The probability of $0$ chimes in a given day would be $e^{-1/6}$, so the probability of getting at least one chime on a given day would be $1-e^{-1/6}$. By the linearity of expectation, we should expect to see
$$
\mathrm{E}(A)=30\left(1-e^{-1/6}\right)\doteq 4.605548
$$
days with at least one chime.

Answer (score 0):

$30/6$ is the total expected number of chimes over 30 days, which is not what you want because some days can have multiple chimes. So your answer should be less than $5$. The second approach you outlined is the right way to go, and gives the right answer by linearity of expectation.